# Webscraping in Python; pagination problem

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, jupyter-notebook, screen-scraping

I am still a beginner so Im sorry if this is a stupid question. I am trying to scrape some new articles for my master analysis through Jupyter notebook, but I am struggling with pagination. How can I fix that?

Here is the code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import pandas as pd

danas = []

base_url = 'https://www.danas.rs/tag/izbori-2020/page/'
r = requests.get(base_url)
c = r.content

soup = BeautifulSoup(c,"html.parser")
    
paging = soup.find("div",{"column is-8"}).find("div",{"nav-links"}).find_all("a")
start_page = paging[1].int
last_page = paging[len(paging)-1].int
web_content_list = []

for page_number in range(int(float(start_page)),int(float(last_page)) + 1):
    
    url = base_url+str(page_number)+"/.html"
    r = requests.get(base_url+str(page_number))
    c = r.content
    soup = BeautifulSoup(c,"html.parser")
    
    if r.status_code == 200:
        soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')
    
        try:
            headline = soup.find('h1', {'class': 'post-title'}).text.strip()
        except:
            headline = None
            
        try:
            time = soup.find('time', {'class': 'entry-date published'}).text.strip()[:17]
        except:
            time = None
            
        try:
            descr = soup.find('div', {'class': 'post-intro-content content'}).text.strip()
        except:
            descr = None
           
        try:
            txt = soup.find('div', {'class': 'post-content content'}).text.strip()
        except:
            txt = None
            
        # create a list with all scraped info
        danas = [headline,
                        date,
                        time,
                        descr,
                        txt]
        
        web_content_list.append(danas)
            
    else:
        print('Oh No! ' + l)
        
dh = pd.DataFrame(danas)
dh.head()
```

**And here is the error that pops out:**

```
*AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-10-1c9e3a7e6f48> in <module>
     11 soup = BeautifulSoup(c,"html.parser")
     12 
---> 13 paging = soup.find("div",{"column is-8"}).find("div",{"nav-links"}).find_all("a")
     14 start_page = paging[1].int
     15 last_page = paging[len(paging)-1].int
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find'*
```

Comment: are you trying to get all the articles on each page?

Answer (score 0):

Well one issue is that `'https://www.danas.rs/tag/izbori-2020/page/'` returns `Greška 404: Tražena stranica nije pronađena.` on the initial request. So wil lneed to address that.

Second issue is pulling in the start page and end page. Just curious, why would you search for a start page? All pages start at 1.

Another question, why convert to float, then int. Just get the page as int.

3rd, you never declare your variable `date`.

4th you are only grabbing the 1st article on the page. Is that what you want? Or do you want all the articles on the page? I left your code as is, since you're question is referring to iterating through the pages.

5th If you want the full text of the articles, you'll need to get to each of the article links.

There are few more issues too with the code. I tried to comment so you could see it. So compare this code to yours, and if you have questions, let me know:

**Code:**

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import pandas as pd



base_url = 'https://www.danas.rs/tag/izbori-2020/'
r = requests.get(base_url)
c = r.text

soup = BeautifulSoup(c,"html.parser")
    
paging = soup.find("div",{"column is-8"}).find("div",{"nav-links"}).find_all("a")
start_page = 1
last_page = int(paging[1].text)
web_content_list = []

for page_number in range(int(start_page),int(last_page) + 1):
    
    url = base_url+ 'page/' + str(page_number) #<-- fixed this
    r = requests.get(url)
    c = r.text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(c,"html.parser")
    
    if r.status_code == 200:
        soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')
        articles = soup.find_all('article')
        for article in articles:
            w=1
        try:
            headline = soup.find('h2', {'class': 'article-post-title'}).text.strip()
        except:
            headline = None
            
        try:
            time = soup.find('time')['datetime']
        except:
            time = None
            
        try:
            descr = soup.find('div', {'class': 'article-post-excerpt'}).text.strip()
        except:
            descr = None
           
            
        # create a list with all scraped info   <--- changed to dictionary so that you have column:value when you create the dataframe
        danas = {'headline':headline,
                        'time':time,
                        'descr':descr}
        
        web_content_list.append(danas)
        print('Collected: %s of %s' %(page_number, last_page))
            
    else:
        #print('Oh No! ' + l) #<--- what is l? 
        print('Oh No!')
        
dh = pd.DataFrame(web_content_list) #<-- need to get the full appended list, not the danas, as thats overwritten after each iteration
dh.head()
```

**Output:**

```
print(dh.head().to_string())
                                                                     headline                       time                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           descr
0                             Vučić saopštava ime mandatara vlade u 20 časova  2020-10-05T09:00:05+02:00                                                                                                                                   Predsednik Aleksandar Vučić  će u danas, nakon sastanka Predsedništva Srpske napredne stranke (SNS) saopštiti ime mandatara za sastav nove Vlade Srbije. Vučić će odluku saopštiti u 20 sati u Palati Srbija, rečeno je FoNetu u kabinetu predsednika Srbije.
1                                                 Nova skupština i nova vlada  2020-08-01T14:00:13+02:00                                                                                                                                                                        Saša Radulović biće poslanik još nekoliko dana i prvi je objavio da se vrši dezinfekcija skupštinskih prostorija, što govori u prilog tome da će se novi saziv, izabran 21. juna, ipak zakleti u Domu Narodne skupštine.
2      Brnabić o novom mandatu: To ne zavisi od mene, SNS ima dobre kandidate  2020-07-15T18:59:43+02:00                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              Premijerka Ana Brnabić izjavila je danas da ne zavisi od nje da li će i u novom mandatu biti na čelu Vlade Srbije.
3        Državna izborna komisija objavila prve rezultate, HDZ ubedljivo vodi  2020-07-05T21:46:56+02:00                                                                                                                                                                        Državna izborna komisija (DIP) objavila je večeras prve nepotpune rezultate po kojima vladajuća Hrvatska demokratska zajednica (HDZ) osvaja čak 69 mandata, ali je reč o rezultatima na malom broju prebrojanih glasova.
4  Analiza Pravnog tima liste „Šabac je naš“: Ozbiljni dokazi za krađu izbora  2020-07-02T10:53:57+02:00  Na osnovu izjave 123 birača, od kojih je 121 potpisana i sa matičnim brojem, prikupljenim u roku od 96 sati nakon zatvaranja biračkih mesta u nedelju 21. 6. 2020. godine u 20 časova, uočena su 263 kršenja propisa na 55 biračkih mesta, navodi se na početku Analize koju je o kršenju izbornih pravila 21. juna i uoči izbora sačinio pravni tim liste „Nebojša Zelenović – Šabac je naš“.
```